# What's so special about £88.88?

Tags: mathematics

£88.88 is a special amount. Your task is to find out why.

Your answer should follow this acronym: SONACIGC.

Comment: https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081112132641AA4MDrM

Comment: Spoiler. The answer is not true in Sctoland

Comment: Sctoland is one of the most beautiful countries ever, it's so magical, oh those luminous farts coming from the ground are so freaking awesome!

Comment: Why does it not apply in Scotland? (Assuming that is what you meant to type?)

Comment: Not true is Scotland, Nothern Island or Jersey.

Comment: @Jodrell Not that I'm disputing what you're saying, but are you paying attention to the `GC` part of the accepted answer?

Comment: Nice answers but, is it not the value at which money travels through time?

Comment: Hint: The US equivalent is $186.41.

Comment: Seven of Nine and Chakotay in Gothic cathedral?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> $£88.88$ is the sum of all the currency sizes for the pound sterling.
>
>  The pound sterling is composed of [8 coins](http://resources.woodlands-junior.kent.sch.uk/customs/questions/money/coins.htm) from $1p$ to $£2$ and [4 banknotes](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes/pages/current/default.aspx) from $£5$ to $£50$. If we sum them all together we have:
>
>  $1p + 2p + 5p + 10p + 20p + 50p = 88p$
>
>  $£1 + £2 + £5 + £10 + £20 + £50 = £88$
>
>  $88p + £88 = £88.88$
>
>  With this in mind we can say that the **SONACIGC** acronym means (thanks to @Agnesi and @Tim Couwelier for the first part):
>
>  **S**um **O**f **N**otes **A**nd **C**oins **I**n **G**eneral **C**irculation
>
> (Altough I find Kevin Cruijssen's interpretation more suited)

Comment: I had the amounts figured out. I reached 'Sum of notes and coins' for the first bit, but can't figure out the rest.

Comment: The fact that there are 8 letters should help, but I can't find out anything which makes sense.

Comment: maybe its rot13(fhz bs abgrf naq pbvaf va trareny pvephyngvba)?

Comment: @TimCouwelier Thanks for the first part of the acronym. With it, it was easy to figure out the remaining (see my answer).

Comment: Looking at both attempts for finishing the acronym: I doubt id have come up with any of them. Also, i was a little stumped you have no denominations over 50... In euro the answer would be 888.88...

Answer (score 8):

> **SONACIGC** = Sum of Notes and Coins in Given Currency
>
>
>  So: 
>  0.01 + 0.02 + 0.05 + 0.10 + 0.20 + 0.50 +
>  1.00 + 2.00 + 5.00 + 20.00 + 50.00 = £ 88.88

Thanks to *Tim Couwelier* for the first part of the acronym though. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the total value of the coinage + notes used in England

1p + 2p + 5p + 10p + 20p + 50p + £1 + £2 + £5 + £10 + £20 + £50

= £88.88

**But I didn't get what the acronym was about**

Comment: You're five hours too late! :)

Comment: Ya, I guess so.